# SAPUI5 Check model attribute in view

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sapui5

I have a model attached to my view:

**Controller code:**

```
var model =
{
    title:"Scan RFID container",
    question:"Please scan the RFID tag on the container",
    answer:"",
    type:"input",
    options:"",
    transaction : ""
};

var oQuestion = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oQuestion.setData(model);
this.getView().setModel(oQuestion, "containerChecks");
```

In my view I can set the texts etc by using the curly brackets. This ofcourse only works for sapui5 elements that parse this content.

**View code**

```
this.page = new sap.m.Page({
    title: "{containerChecks>/title}",
    content: [
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "{containerChecks>/question}"
        })
    ],
});
```

However I want to do a check based on my model attribute `'options'`.

I tried:

```
  var options = this.getModel("containerChecks").getProperty("options");
```

but `getModel` returns `null`

Comment: That last line `var options = this.getModel...`, where is it exactly placed? Inside the view, inside an inner function, or inside the controller?

Comment: @Qualiture Inside the view in createContent

Comment: If it's directly within createContent() method of your view, then this.getModel("containerChecks") should not return null... can you post a JSBin example?

Comment: @Qualiture http://jsbin.com/gedegora/1/edit . The trigger is _handleRouteMatched with sequence 1

Comment: @Qualiture I found the issue, the createContent is called before the _handleRouteMatched. I need to move the logic that binds the model to the view. But whereto?

Comment: Normally you would initialize the model in the controller's `onInit` method. I would just initialize the model with the first question inside this init method, the subsequent questions would then be handled from the navigation event handler

Comment: In addition, be aware the `createContent` method is only called once! I would restructure your app to use dynamic property binding / keeping track of the current question, this would eliminate the need for setting the model everytime you move to the next question

Comment: @Qualiture thank you for your valued input. You can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As your setting the model in **View** by using `this.getView().setModel()` how can you access the model through `this.getModel()` try this

```
var options = this.getView().getModel("containerChecks").getProperty("options");
```

If your using above statement in a `Controller`.

I am sure that it may give you the `options` value.